# pendrive detected but not shown on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, usb-drive, dmesg

When I plug my Pendrive I hear the sound of it getting detected.

`output of dmesg`

```
[21145.916189] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[21146.522765] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=1234, bcdDevice= 0.01
[21146.522779] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[21146.522784] usb 1-1: Product: Mass Storage Device
[21146.522789] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
[21146.526401] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[21146.526992] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[21147.528953] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[21147.529520] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[21147.589044] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`lsusb output`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1866 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am not sure why the pendrive is not showing up. Also it is not visible in gparted.
what might have gone wrong.

`sudo fdisk -l output`

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.51 MiB, 58191872 bytes, 113656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 128.85 MiB, 135090176 bytes, 263848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 55.45 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 32.42 MiB, 33980416 bytes, 66368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 65.22 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.89 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0AED2D84-4932-4AF4-A2B3-C9F4134C44A3

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     567296  419997695 419430400   200G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4  419997696  836227071 416229376 198.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5  836227072 1255657471 419430400   200G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1255657472 1570230271 314572800   150G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1999077376 2000408575   1331200   650M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p8 1570230272 1999077375 428847104 204.5G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop8: 32.45 MiB, 34017280 bytes, 66440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 218.102 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 162.89 MiB, 170778624 bytes, 333552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 164.78 MiB, 172761088 bytes, 337424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

output of `lsblk -f`

```
nvme0n1                                                                            
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     SYSTEM    88CB-E8E2                             222.6M    13% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                                                                        
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     OS        4A84CDA084CD8F3F                                    
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     Documents 3214B0F814B0C061                                    
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     Software  24B6273DB6270F3C                       41.4G    79% /home/USER/ssds
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     General   0C4E38684E384D28                        2.5G    98% /media/USER/General
├─nvme0n1p7 ntfs               36F054AEF0547659                                    
└─nvme0n1p8 ext4               942a77ae-27b6-4e4d-80c5-e35a46b8661b   43.1G    73% /
```

Comment: It is recognized by the system, but may have no partition table or partition. Check also the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: it is not listed in ```sudo fdisk -l```

Comment: Strange. `dmesg` clearly seems to indicate it is detected.

Comment: I have added the output of ```sudo fdisk -l```

Comment: According to your dmesg output it would make sense to to see the output of  `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`, also check if the device is shown with `lsblk -f`.

Comment: out put of ```sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda``` is ```fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No medium found
```

Comment: device is not shown in ```lsblk -f```

Comment: You can find some more ways to analyze the problem in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.